# Where does/did Stylish on Safari (mac) store css styles?

Tags: mac, safari, safari-extensions, stylish

Where does/did Stylish, an extension, on Safari (mac) store settings like custom css styles?

Apple just pulled support for Stylish and I had a bunch of custom styles for many of websites I frequently visit, that I would like retrieve and import to Cascadea, that I have started to use as a replacement.